# THREE.js ArrowHelper not obeying intrinsic Euler angle rotation

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like to set intrinsic rotations to a `THREE.ArrowHelper`. From my understanding, THREE.js natively uses intrinsic Tait-Bryan euler angles to represent 3D rotations.

In the code below, I create a unit vector representing the x-axis, `THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0)`.

I then rotate it about the Y and Z axis by an arbitrary amount.

Since there was some rotation about Y and Z, the X axis of the local coordinate system (which I assume points along the red vector) has also changed.

So, when I apply a rotation about `X`, I don't expect the arrow to move at all (except rotate in place...but that shouldn't be visible).

Instead, I see the arrow sweeping around, as if it's rotating about some arbitrary axis, and not its local x axis.

Thanks for any assistance!

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var origin = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
var xDir = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0);
var length = 1;
var arrow = new THREE.ArrowHelper(xDir, origin, length, 0xff0000);
arrow.rotation.order = 'XYZ';
arrow.rotation.y = 0.5;
arrow.rotation.z = 0.5;
scene.add(arrow);

camera.position.z = 5;

var animate = function () {
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );

 arrow.rotation.x += 0.01;
  
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
};

animate();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: if you remove `arrow.rotation.y = 0.5; arrow.rotation.z = 0.5;` the arrow doesn't move at all, only rotates in place (barely visible), is that what you meant by *I don't expect the arrow to move at all (except rotate in place...but that shouldn't be visible).*?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. But I expect it to do that even when the rotation about Y and Z are applied, since the subsequent rotation about X should be about its local X coordinate frame.

Comment: i'm afraid you won't be able to do that. the minute you rotate the Y and/or Z axes you are affecting the position (and rotation) of the X axis of the arrow. The important thing to notice which is the reason it behaves like that is that when you change any of the axes, the whole space doesn't change with it, you're just affecting the arrow, which means the *imaginary* X axis is not moving which is why the arrow keeps rotating around it but not on it self. maybe it's not the best way to explain it but that's my best shot :/

Comment: Is the *imaginary* X axis you're talking about the world x axis? Because an intrinsic rotation (which is what THREE.js does by default) shouldn't be rotating about the world's x-axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `ArrowHelper` is doing its own special rotation math. It creates a unit arrow facing up (+Y). It the uses custom math to setup the orientation to make that line point in the given direction in local space.

You can see this if you just create the arrow and then print the rotation

```
  var origin = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
  var xDir = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0);
  var length = 1;
  var arrow = new THREE.ArrowHelper(xDir, origin, length, color);
  console.log(arrow.rotation.x, arrow.rotation.y, arrow.rotation.z);
```

You'll see rotation.z is already set to rotate the +Y arrow to face +X so then you go and change those rotations and the arrow is no longer based facing +X.

That means manipulating the arrow via `arrow.rotation` won't work as expected.

If you parent the arrow to an `Object3D` and then rotate that object it will work as expected (or as I expect it )

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(10, 10));

function addArrow(x, ry, rz, color) {
  var origin = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
  var xDir = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0);
  var length = 1;
  var arrow = new THREE.ArrowHelper(xDir, origin, length, color);

  var ob = new THREE.Object3D();
  ob.position.x = x;
  ob.rotation.order = 'XYZ';
  ob.rotation.y = ry;
  ob.rotation.z = rz;
  scene.add(ob);  
  ob.add(arrow);
  return ob;
}

addArrow(-4,   0,   0, 0xFF0000);
addArrow(-2,   0, 0.5, 0x00FF00);
addArrow( 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0xFFFF00);
const arrow = addArrow( 2, 0.5, 0.5, 0x00FFFF);

camera.position.z = 6;

const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.target.set(0, 0, 0);
controls.update();

var animate = function () {
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
   arrow.rotation.x += 0.01;

  renderer.render( scene, camera );
};
animate();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.115.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.115.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

What I expect.

Rotations are in the local coodinate system. Rotation order 'XYZ' means, assuming you only had the arrow the full matrix calculation would be

```
matrix = projection * 
         view *
         obTranslation *
         obXAxisRotation * 
         obYAxisRotation * 
         obZAxisRotation * 
         obScale * 
         arrowOrientation;
```

In any case

```
var origin = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
var xDir = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0);
var length = 1;
var arrow = new THREE.ArrowHelper(xDir, origin, length, 0xff0000);
var ob = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add(ob);
ob.add(arrow);
ob.rotation.order = 'XYZ';
```

Viewed from 0, 0, 5 this gives us an arrow pointing right.

I like to look at matrices as applied from the right to the left so looking at the formula above first scale will be applied. It's 1,1,1 so no change

Next zAxisRotation is applied. 0.5 radians is about 30 degrees so the arrow is now either pointing 30 degrees up

Next yAxisRotation is applied. The 30 degree up arrow is now pointing 30 degrees back as into the distance.

Next xAxisRotation is applyed so this funkily pointed arrow will spin around x

run it and drag on the sample above to look from above. You'll see it matches the description.

So it's up to you then. You can make a +X facing ArrowHelper and parent it to an Object3D or you can just know that an ArrowHelper actually makes a +Y arrow and then set the rotations appropriately knowing that.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I've never used THREE.js, but I'll try to visualize my point with this answer. The imaginary or world axis is represented by the gray arrow, notice how when you toggle Y and Z axes values, it affects the red arrow but not the other gray arrow, that's what I meant by *the imaginary X axis is not moving*.

Your red arrow is still rotating around the X axis but not *its* X axis, but the *world's* which is why when you change *the arrow's* Y and Z axes it looks like it's sweeping around when in actuality it just continues to rotate around the same fixed axis it was rotating around since the beginning.

Well, I really expect I didn't make more a mess than an explanation.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var origin = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
var xDir = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0);
var length = 1;
var arrow = new THREE.ArrowHelper(xDir, origin, length, 0xff0000);
var imaginaryXAxis = new THREE.ArrowHelper(xDir, origin, length+100, 0xffffff);
arrow.rotation.order = 'XYZ';
/*arrow.rotation.y = 0.5;
arrow.rotation.z = 0.5;*/
scene.add(arrow);
scene.add(imaginaryXAxis);

camera.position.z = 2;

var animate = function () {
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
   arrow.rotation.x += 0.01;

  renderer.render( scene, camera );
};
animate();

const yValue = arrow.rotation.y, zValue = arrow.rotation.z;

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.target.classList.toggle('affected')
    if(e.target.classList.contains('affected')){
      arrow.rotation.y=.5;
      arrow.rotation.z=.5;
      e.target.textContent = "Reset Y and Z to zero";
    } else {
      arrow.rotation.y=yValue;
      arrow.rotation.z=zValue;
      e.target.textContent = "Affect Y and Z";
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>

<button>Affect Y and Z</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I completely agree with what you're saying but the reason I was confused is because the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Euler.order) says that the rotations are applied with respect to the local coordinate system, not the "world" coordinate system where the imaginary X-axis lies.